# Why doesn't Windows Explorer display OpenSearch results with types other than text/html correctly?

Tags: search, windows-explorer, atom-feed, opensearch

I'm trying to display results from the REST API of IBM Content Analytics in Windows 7 Explorer through its OpenSearch integration. The REST API returns an Atom feed with an `<atom:entry>` element for each search hit.

My problem is: As soon as the `type` attribute of an element's `<atom:link>` has a value other than `text/html`, the respective search hit in Windows explorer is displayed as "No information available". In the below minimal example, the search hit is displayed correctly as soon as you remove the `type="application/msword"` or change its value to `text/html`.

```xml
<atom:entry>
  <atom:title>Hit B</atom:title>
  <atom:link rel="alternate" type="application/msword" href="http://192.168.111.130:8394/api/v10/document/content?collection=Search&amp;uri=file:///C:/DataFiles/Price%2BChange.doc" hreflang="en"/>
  <atom:id>file:///C:/DataFiles/Price+Change.doc</atom:id>
  <atom:summary>...B</atom:summary>
</atom:entry>
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour or say how to avoid it and display non-`text/html` results in Windows Explorer?

Documentation seems scarce, most of the stuff I found was in the two documents linked below, but I didn't find anything on this issue there.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2010/04/18/windows-7-federated-search.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In RSS, the link tag needs to contain a URL e.g.

```
<link>http://www.google.com</link>.
```

Then the title, date, etc. are displayed in the file manager.

Instead

```
<link href="http://www.google.com" />
```

would show "No information available" in the file manager.

For ATOM, you need to include:

```
<link href="http://www.google.com" />
```

without any "rel" attribute. Then you see the correct information in the file manager!

Comment: According to [RFC 4287](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4287), section 4.1.2, the `atom:entry` element _MUST_ contain at least one `atom:link` element – so that means that either Windows Explorer forces me to not comply with the Atom RFC.
My question really was about why removing the `type` attribute from the `atom:link` element fixes things.